# VB6-how to create log file in VB6 while launching application

Tags: logging, vb6

I want to log the exceptions occurred during execution of my app. Before this I handled it with message box. I am new to VB 6.

Please provide some sample code to create log file and to save exception messages.

Thanks..

Comment: http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5798663.html
 That seems to be pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need error handlers, using `On Error Goto`, so that you can execute your own code when an error occurs. (BTW in VB6 they are called *errors* not *exceptions*.)  The free tool [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) is excellent - it can automatically insert the `On Error Goto` and an error handler which includes the name of the current routine.

You also need a general routine that logs error details to a file, a little bit like this below. Health warning - I've just typed this straight in without testing it ([air code](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2005/02/27/56126.aspx)).

```
Sub MySub()
  On Error Goto ErrHandler
  '... Do something ...'
  On Error Goto 0
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  Call LogError("MySub", Err, Error$) ' passes name of current routine '
End Sub 

' General routine for logging errors '
Sub LogError(ProcName$, ErrNum&, ErrorMsg$)
  On Error Goto ErrHandler
  Dim nUnit As Integer
  nUnit = FreeFile
  ' This assumes write access to the directory containing the program '
  ' You will need to choose another directory if this is not possible '
  Open App.Path & App.ExeName & ".log" For Append As nUnit
  Print #nUnit, "Error in " & ProcName
  Print #nUnit, "  " & ErrNum & ", " & ErrorMsg
  Print #nUnit, "  " & Format$(Now)
  Print #nUnit
  Close nUnit
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  'Failed to write log for some reason.'
  'Show MsgBox so error does not go unreported '
  MsgBox "Error in " & ProcName & vbNewLine & _
    ErrNum & ", " & ErrorMsg
End Sub
```

Bonus suggestion: [roll your own stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098863/runtime-error-stacktrace-or-location-in-vb6/1099804#1099804).
Bonus suggestion 2: switch off the error handlers in the IDE with something like this `If Not IsInIDE() Then On Error Goto Handler`, using the `IsInIDE` function from [here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/helpers/isinide.htm)