# AfterColEdit () event - Visual Basic 6 and Apex True DBGrid Pro 6

Tags: vb6, truedbgrid

in a VB 6 application, using True DBGrid 6:

I type a value in the id column;

When I change the column, I do a search in the database to bring the description of that id. In the AfterColEdit () event;

On my machine and some others it works. However, on other machines, this AfterColEdit event is not triggered. I checked on these machines, and the OCX tdbg6.ocx is the same as my machine.

Any ideas why the event is not triggered on some machines?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the _event_ isn't triggered? How did you determine that it isn't triggered? Or does perhaps the lookup fail?

Comment: Hi, I wrote a MsgBox() on this event. And Msgbox() does not shows up. And another workstations, works fine.

Comment: I'm not a fan of MsgBox for debugging purposes, that's what the `Debug.Print` statement is for. In an ideal world, your application has some kind of [logging capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055264/vb6-how-to-create-log-file-in-vb6-while-launching-application), which you use both to trace the program flow and log application states (errors) and variable values. Also: disable any error handling while tracking down the problem. _That_ one has cost me quite some time.

Comment: More likely it is failing at some point before the messagebox is called, or even before the event is raised