# visual basic debug environment

Tags: vb6

I inherited a project in Visual Basic, and I am assigned to fixing errors in this project. Users have reported that there are issues with a fresh install of the project, and I was able to reproduce the errors. There were also issues related to running this on non-compatibility mode on Windows 7. I tried running this project in Visual Basic 6, and I was not able to reproduce some of these errors.

I want to know if there is any way to match the debugging environment in Visual Basic 6 to the installed environment (after unpacking the project with an installation package).

All answers are welcomed and appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Um... A virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to provide some guesswork answers to your problems, and answer your specific question last of all.

- Is the install package installing all the necessary dependencies? COM components, data files, configuration settings, etc.
- Are the Windows 7 problems caused by [storing application data under program files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273424/where-should-i-store-application-specific-settings)?

Some strategies for finding the problem:

1. Reading the code. Can be the fastest method.
2. Add logging to the application, so you can study the behaviour on an installed system (virtual machine?)
3. Try to debug on an installed system which doesn't have the VB6 IDE installed. [Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019071/how-to-use-vb6-debugger-on-outlook-property-page-ocx) but not easy - try steps 1 and 2 first.